# WCF http chunking Channel

Tags: c#, wcf, http, channel, chunking

Currently I am working on the chunking channel which allows the client to upload big data. I am looking around the website and find that the sample from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/chunking-channel
is very useful. but I have 2 questions here:

1. The sample is using TcpChunkingChannel, I would like something
   like HttpChunkingChannel. I found some sample code but not work
   properly.
2. Is it possible that the parameters of web method could be something else like List<> rather than Stream?

I do not want the client to do the chunk. Does any one happen to have some sample code of HttpChunkingChannel?

thanks

Comment: Please share code of HttpChunkingChannel that is not working.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cf1680d-65da-4152-af39-49478e98e55a/chunking-channel-with-ws-reliable-sessions?forum=wcf  here is the httpChunkingChannel code. when I added it. the upload file is empty. debugging found that the namespace is not correct. there must be some more steps needed.